# The fastest way to create an ordered structure and retrieve values from it in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to create an ordered "structure" in R so that either the first (or last) element is always the smallest. Currently, I am going about it in the following way:

I have a sorted vector of ascending numerical values and I input new values in it so that the ordering is kept. Then when I want the next element (meaning the smallest one), I just take the first element and delete it from the vector.

```
# Input the new element
point <- Position(function(v) v < ins, ordVec, right = TRUE)
if (is.na(point)) {point <- 0}
ordVec <- append(ordVec, ins, after = point)
# Get the smallest element
value <- ordVec[1]
ordVec <- ordVec[-1]
```

where `ordVec` is the ordered vector and `ins` is the value I want to input.
E.g., I have `ordVec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and `ins <- 2.5`, and after inputing `ins` I get `c(1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5)`. Then, the `value` is `1` and the resulting vector is `c(2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5)`.

I am doing this as a part of a `while` loop and when the `ordVec` is long, it takes quite a long time.

Does there exist a faster way, be it using something other than the described procedure to get an ordered "structure", or modifying the described procedure and the element retrieval?

Comment: A loop with the append function is just slow.  Each call to the append function is making a copy of the vector in memory and if the vector is long it can become noticeable if done repeatedly.  Is it possible to just to merge the vectors once and then sort just once?

Comment: @Dave2e I am aware of this, but I found no other alternative. Sadly no, I cannot do that, as I am simulating queues and the times and actions are random and dependant on the previous event execution time, service availability and waiting room availability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies with the Position function. Since your vector is already sorted, you don't need this. If you look at the code, it actually loops through the vector, meaning it will bum along if the vector is long:

```
Position
function (f, x, right = FALSE, nomatch = NA_integer_) 
{
    ind <- if (right) 
        rev(seq_along(x))
    else seq_along(x)
    for (i in ind) if (f(x[[i]])) 
        return(i)
    nomatch
}
```

So let's try a few solutions:

```
f_position = function(ordVec,ins){
point <- Position(function(v) v < ins, ordVec, right = TRUE)
ordVec <- append(ordVec, ins, after = point)
return(c(ordVec[1],ordVec[-1]))
}

f_which = function(ordVec,ins){
point <- max(which(ordVec < ins))
ordVec <- append(ordVec, ins, after = point)
return(c(ordVec[1],ordVec[-1]))
}

f_interval = function(ordVec,ins){
point <- findInterval(ins,ordVec)
ordVec <- append(ordVec, ins, after = point)
return(c(ordVec[1],ordVec[-1]))
}
```

And see their timing, I use a presorted vector, and 1 insertion value:

```
set.seed(111)
VEC = sort(runif(10000))
INS = 0.5
microbenchmark(f_position(VEC,INS),times=1000,unit="ms")
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max
 f_position(VEC, INS) 2.525094 2.667763 3.040159 2.769987 2.923979 29.5144
 neval
  1000

microbenchmark(f_which(VEC,INS),times=1000,unit="ms")
Unit: milliseconds
              expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 f_which(VEC, INS) 0.148981 0.182694 0.3350992 0.197149 0.396787 28.04375  1000

microbenchmark(f_interval(VEC,INS),times=1000,unit="ms")
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr      min      lq      mean  median       uq      max
 f_interval(VEC, INS) 0.121805 0.15208 0.2851541 0.16236 0.201172 30.68901
 neval
  1000
```

I think you are better off using max(which()) or findInterval(), you just need to figure out how to initialize but should not be a problem.

Comment: This helps a lot, the code is much faster with findInterval(). Now the bottlenecks are the append and ordVec[-1] functions. I presume I can't do anything about them?

Comment: ordVec[-1] should be ok, that's no cost at all. you can try c(ordVec[1:point], ins, ordVec[(point+1):length(ordVec)]), but I doubt that improves it much

Comment: Did you actually check your code again? Position is the most costly, going by the above, you shave off 99% of the time required

Comment: I did and it does improve the speed by a lot. I was just wondering if it was possible to speed it up even more. But you are right, it is incomparably faster now.